# Tradução do privilégio "acesso às estatísticas do site" (25k)

Tags: bug, tradução

[Na lista de privilégios da central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), o privilégio mais elevado - *acesso às estatísticas do site* - está com o texto em inglês:

> **25.000      access to site analytics      Access to internal and Google site analytics**

Ao clicar para ver detalhes desse privilégio, [o conteúdo também está em inglês](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics), assim como o *milestone* da direita:

[image: Print do conteúdo não traduzido]

Comment: Vira e mexe alguma coisa no site muda pra inglês e depois volta pra português.

Comment: Sim. Acho que ja vi algum post aqui dizendo que parece ser um problema com atualização no SE, que estava sobrepondo as traduções. Várias notificações de _destraduções_